# How to round down money and then distribute remaining pennies among ranked players?

Tags: c#

I have a leaderboard of players who are ranked in decreasing order of points. Also, there is a list of Rank prizes ordered on increasing rank. Each player opts in at a certain point in time in the leaderboard contest. For example,

```
RankedPlayers                    RankPrizes
-------------                    ----------
Player-3 (Points = 500)          Rank-1 Prize ($500.00)
Player-4 (Points = 400)          Rank-2 Prize ($300.00)
Player-2 (Points = 200)          Rank-3 Prize ($250.01)
Player-1 (Points = 200)
Player-5 (Points = 200)
```

When more than one Player is tied they will share the same rank and the next x ranks will be skipped. All prizes from the tied rank up to the last skipped rank will be summed and split amongst the tied players.
For instance, in the above case `Player-2, Player-1, Player-5` are `tied`

If the summed prize amount split isn’t even, round down and calculate the difference in change lost from rounding. Distribute the rounding error evenly amongst players in order of opt in time. `Each extra penny would be allocated in order of opt-in time.`
For example:

```
Player-2, Player-1, Player-5 are TIED with total prize money to be shared $250.01
They opted in the leaderboard in order of: Player-1, Player-5, Player-2 
So their split of $250.01 should be:
Player-1: $83.34
Player-5: $83.34
Player-2: $83.33
```

How do I split the money among the players? In case of even split, it's easy I can divy up the amount(= total/nplayers) for each player.

Comment: I think I can solve it by multiplying the amount by 100 and that converts to cents.

so something like this

`var amountInCentsTotal = amount * 100;
 var amountInCentsPerPlayer = (amountInCentsTotal / nplayers);
 var amountInCentsDelta = amountInCentsTotal - (amountInCentsPerPlayer * nplayers);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
Winning Players:
  Points Players
     500 Player-3
     400 Player-4
     200 Player-1,Player-2,Player-5
     100 Player-6

Current Status:
Player       Points   Money
Player-1     200      $83.34
Player-2     200      $83.33
Player-3     500      $500.00
Player-4     400      $300.00
Player-5     200      $83.34
Player-6     100      $0.00
```

and the code below. I used `GroupBy()` to group the players by the points.

```
public class Player
{
    public Player(string name, int points)
    {
        Name=name;
        Points=points;
        Money = 0m;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public decimal Money { get; set; }
}

public class Prize
{
    public Prize(int rank, decimal value)
    {
        Rank=rank;
        Value=value;
    }

    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var players = new Player[] {
            new Player(2, "Player-1", 200),
            new Player(5, "Player-2", 200),
            new Player(4, "Player-3", 500),
            new Player(1, "Player-4", 400),
            new Player(3, "Player-5", 200),
            new Player(6, "Player-6", 100),
        };

        var prizes = new Prize[] {
            new Prize(1, 500m),
            new Prize(2, 300m),
            new Prize(3, 250.01m),
        };

       
        // In ranked order just in case of bad data
        Array.Sort(prizes, (x, y) => x.Rank.CompareTo(y.Rank));

        Console.WriteLine("Winning Players:");
        Console.WriteLine($"{"Points",8} {"Players"}");
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var group in players.GroupBy((item) => item.Points).OrderByDescending(g=>g.FirstOrDefault().Points))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{group.Key,8} {string.Join(",", group.Select((g) => g.Name))}");
            if (index<prizes.Length)
            {
                var prize = prizes[index].Value;
                var amount = Math.Ceiling( prize/group.Count()*100)/100;
                var sum = 0m;
                foreach (var player in group.OrderBy( (p)=>p.Order) )
                {
                    var actual = Math.Min(amount, prize-sum);
                    sum += actual;
                    player.Money += actual;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
            index++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Current Status:");
        Console.WriteLine($"{"Player",-12} {"Points",-8} {"Money",-8}");
        foreach (var player in players)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{player.Name,-12} {player.Points,-8} {player.Money,-8:c}");
        }
    }
}
```

Some points to be made here.

1. What happens if there aren't enough players for all the prizes? This hasn't been addressed explicitly, but the default is to leave money on the table.
2. What happens if there are too many players? The code above stops the money-giving-out loop (see the `break` keyword).
3. Keep a tally of the money given out and trim the last players in the sorting to make sure the pennies are given out properly.
4. Sort players when dividing prizes according to their order in the leaderboard (`players` array here).

Comment: I have nearly the same implementation as yours. Additionally, handling the pennies too which was what I originally asked in the question about how to distribute.

Comment: You can round down for the `n` players the pennies and keep the difference. Use `var amount = Math.Floor( prizes[index].Value/group.Count()*100)/100;` instead above.

Comment: @Monku - I misread the question to begin with. Now I think I sorted it all out. Please check above if the algo works as intended.